# Running terminal commands on Android Studio

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, terminal, runtime.exec

I'm trying to make an app that allows me to switch scaling governors of my phone (yes I am rooted). After much searching, i found that I am generally required to run the command off `process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

However, after many times of trying, the app doesn't seem to respond properly. This is my code thus far.

```
    String RunCommand(String cmd) {
    StringBuffer cmdOut = new StringBuffer();
    Process process;
    try{
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        InputStreamReader r = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(r);
        char[] buf = new char[4096];
        int nRead = 0;
        while ((nRead = bufReader.read(buf)) > 0){
            cmdOut.append(buf, 0, nRead);
        }
        bufReader.close();
        try {
            process.waitFor();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cmdOut.toString();
}
```

In fact, I do not need an output file since the commands I am running don't really need an output. i.e `echo performance > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

When I run the app, it either hangs or just does nothing. Not sure what I am doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I use for my apps:

```
fun sudo(vararg strings: String) {
    try {
        val su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su")
        val outputStream = DataOutputStream(su.outputStream)

        for (s in strings) {
            outputStream.writeBytes(s + "\n")
            outputStream.flush()
        }

        outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n")
        outputStream.flush()
        try {
            su.waitFor()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        outputStream.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

It's in Kotlin, but it's easy to convert to Java.

The key part, I believe, is starting your new Process (`exec()`) with `su`. The function then writes the command(s) you send to the OutputStream, so it runs them under the `su` process.

If your app is hanging, make sure that you're granting it root access with whatever manager you use (Magisk, SuperSU, etc).

Comment: thanks for your help! One more thing, is it right to say that DataOutputStream is generally for entering terminal commands (for my use case), and DataInputStream is for getting the results from terminal (if any)? 

Or can I use something like this for the results?
"BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));"

Comment: @NicholasKoh yes